# How do I print the person name in DNA PSET5 CS50x

Tags: python, python-3.x, cs50

I don't know how to print the person's name that matches the numbers (as strings) returned from "list4"
(sorry for bad english) So I use `print(list4)` and I get the right values, but I don't know how to get
the name from the person. Example : `list4 = ['4', '1', '5']`, so how I get 'Bob'? I would appreciate any help!

```
import csv
import sys
import itertools
import re
import collections
import json
import functools

def main():

    # TODO: Check for command-line usage
    # not done yet
    filecsv = sys.argv[1]
    filetext = sys.argv[2]
    names = []
    # TODO: Read DNA sequence file into a variable
    with open(filecsv, "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        dict_list = list(reader)
        names.append(dict_list)
    # Open sequences file and convert to list
    with open(filetext, "r") as file:
        sequence = file.read()
    # TODO: Find longest match of each STR in DNA sequence
    find_STR = []
    for i in range(1, len(dict_list[0])):
       find_STR.append(longest_match(sequence, dict_list[0][i]))

    #TODO: Check database for matching profiles
    #convert dict_list to a string
    listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in dict_list])
    #convert find_STR to a string
    A = [str(x) for x in find_STR]   
    # compare both strings
    list3 = set(A)&set(listToStr)
    list4 = sorted(list3, key = lambda k : A.index(k))
    if(list4):
       print(name) # how???`
    return


def longest_match(sequence, subsequence):
    """Returns length of longest run of subsequence in sequence."""

    # Initialize variables
    longest_run = 0
    subsequence_length = len(subsequence)
    sequence_length = len(sequence)

    # Check each character in sequence for most consecutive runs of subsequence
    for i in range(sequence_length):

        # Initialize count of consecutive runs
        count = 0

        # Check for a subsequence match in a "substring" (a subset of characters) within sequence
        # If a match, move substring to next potential match in sequence
        # Continue moving substring and checking for matches until out of consecutive matches
        while True:

            # Adjust substring start and end
            start = i + count * subsequence_length
            end = start + subsequence_length

            # If there is a match in the substring
            if sequence[start:end] == subsequence:
                count += 1

            # If there is no match in the substring
            else:
                break

        # Update most consecutive matches found
        longest_run = max(longest_run, count)

    
    return longest_run


main()
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. Please [edit] your question and post a [mre] - a single, runnable block of code that includes all data and variable definitions, so that we can reproduce what you're seeing. Please read the link for all that's required. For example, the string `'Bob'` doesn't occur anywhere in the code you've shown so far - where does it come from?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want help to know how I print the name of the "winner" I dont know where i get the persons name, I got stuck and I dont have any ideia where I go, Bob per example, "his number dna" is '4', '1', '5', and I get hisnumber(string) from the variable 'list4' but I dont know how link his numbers with his name, from another csv file that contains persons names and their numbers, I load the names in the variable names[], also in dict_list, so if you got any question that I dont answer please let me know that I can update you, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Start by inspecting the values in your variables. For example, look at `dict_list` and `names` for the `small.csv` file and you will find:

```
dict_list:
[['name', 'AGATC', 'AATG', 'TATC'], ['Alice', '2', '8', '3'], ['Bob', '4', '1', '5'], ['Charlie', '3', '2', '5']]
names:
[[['name', 'AGATC', 'AATG', 'TATC'], ['Alice', '2', '8', '3'], ['Bob', '4', '1', '5'], ['Charlie', '3', '2', '5']]]
```

First observation: `dict_list` is a list of lists (not dictionaries). This happens when you set `dict_list = list(reader)`. Use `csv.DictReader()` if you want to create a list of dictionaries. You don't have to create a list of dictionaries, but you will find it makes it much easier to work with the data. Also, there is nothing gained by appending `dict_list` to another list (`names`).

Next, look at `find_STR`. For sequence 1 is: `[4, 1, 5]`. However,  you didn't save the longest match value with the STR sequence name. As a result, you have to reference the first list item in `names` (or `dict_list`).

Once you have the longest match values (in `find_STR`), you need to compare them to the names and sequence counts in `dict_list`, and find the 1 that matches. (For this sequence, it will be `['Bob', '4', '1', '5']`.) Once you find the match, the first item in the list is the name you want: `Bob`.

None of the code to create `A, list3 or list4` do this. They simply return `'4', '1', '5'` as different objects: `A` is a list of strings, `list3` is an unsorted set of strings, and `list4` is a sorted list of strings that matches `A`. There isn't a name there to print.

Good luck.